# Python Unit test debugging in VS code

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I use VS code for my Python projects and we have unit tests written using Python's unittest module. I am facing a weird issue with debugging unit tests.

VSCode Version: May 2018 (1.24)
OS Version: Windows 10

Let's say I have 20 unit tests in a particular project.

I run the tests by right clicking on a unit test file and click 'Run all unit tests'
After the run is complete, the results bar displays how many tests are passed and how many are failed. (e.g. 15 passed, 5 failed).
And I can run/debug individual test because there is a small link on every unit test function for that.
If I re-run the tests from same file, then the results bar displays the **twice** number of tests. (e.g. 30 passed, 10 failed)
Also the links against individual test functions **disappear**. So I cannot run individual tests.
The only way to be able to run/debug individual tests after this is by re-launching the VS code.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I would file a bug at github.com/microsoft/vscode-python if this is for the Python extension for VS Code

Comment: I added a bug! https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2143

Comment: I will delete the question once the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Python extension for VS code and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing issue related to Unit Test debug and Run related issue in VS Code for Linux or Windows. Please follow these two steps.

1. Download Latest Build From VSCode Repo [Download Ling](https://pvsc.blob.core.windows.net/extension-builds/ms-python-insiders.vsix) It will download a .vsix file which is an official extension to be added into next release.
2. Install the downloaded extension (.vsix) by using command `code --install-extension myextension.vsix`  For more detail Read This How to install [Click Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix)

I also faced a lot of issues and struggled a lot. So finally I raised an issue in the official GitHub repository. [Check here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2370#issuecomment-412586278) Which helped me to solve the issue.